# Configure simultaneous audio output with Pipewire

Tags: audio, pipewire

I am trying to configure my audio to output simultaneously to both my TV (HDMI from AMD GPU) and my PC speakers (analog output).

I created a new sink:

> pactl load-module module-null-sink media.class=Audio/Sink sink_name="Simultaneous Audio Output" channel_map=stereo

It appeared as an output option in pavucontrol. I connected this new sink to the original devices with the `Helvum` application, and set this new simultaneous output as the active device in GNOME's sound settings.

I tested and it worked excellently. Unfortunately upon restarting the computer these changes are all lost, and the simultaneous output device I created is no longer listed in GNOME's sound settings or pavucontrol.

I tried deleting the configuration files in `~/.local/state/wireplumber` and rebooting - then re-doing the setup. This did not make a difference, the changes were still lost after reboot.

- I am using openSUSE Tumbleweed with GNOME.
- The pipewire packages were coming from the Packman repo, so I switched them to the Main OSS repository.
- Wireplumber is installed.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1382215/61027 also worked for me on Fedora.

Comment: Thank you for linking that! I am not using combined audio in my setup right now, but if I do again I will give this a try <3

Comment: The linked comment above worked perfectly on my debian 12 with pipewire. As simple as `pactl load-module module-combine-sink` as a user.